# React, render component based on localStorage changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to make an authentication system. Users can sign in and sign out via the top nav bar. The username will store in the local storage. I can find 'user' in my local storage after sign in, and it's gone after signing out.

But it seems that the `useEffect` doesn't work properly, so the top bar doesn't change accordingly. Any help is appreciated.

```
function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    function checkUserData() {
      const user = localStorage.getItem("user");

      if (user) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("storage", checkUserData);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", checkUserData);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <TopBar
          logout={() => {
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
          }}
          loginStatus={isLoggedIn}
        />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="/sign-in/"
            element={
              <SignIn
                toggleLoggedIn={(user) => {
                  localStorage.setItem("user", user);
                }}
              />
            }
          />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
function TopBar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar >
          <Box />

          <Box>
            {props.loginStatus ? (
              <Link
                href="/"
                onClick={props.logout}
                component="button"
              >
                {"Sign Out"}
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <>
                <Link
                  href="/sign-in/"
                >
                  {"Sign In"}
                </Link>
                <Link
                  href="/sign-up/"
                >
                  {"Sign Up"}
                </Link>
              </>
            )}
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Toolbar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `logout` and `toggleLoggedIn` functions as below. You need to `dispach` the `storage` event, because normally, a `storage` change is not noticed in the same document that's is making the changes.

```js
() => {
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
}
```

```js
(user) => {
 localStorage.setItem("user", user);
 window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
}
```

Then change `checkUserData` as below, to handle the `else` case, and change `isLoggedIn` to `false`.

```js
function checkUserData() {
  const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
  if (user) {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  }else{
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  }
}
```

And finally change your `isLoggedIn` definition as below, so you set the login state dynamically according to what's in the `storage` from previous visit:

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(localStorage.getItem("user") ? true : false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't change the boolean isLoggedIn. So the navbar don't know when to update.

You have to do something like this :

```
if (user) {
  setIsLoggedIn(true);
} else {
  setIsLoggedIn(false);
}
```

or something on unmount like

```
useEffect(() => {return () => setIsLoggedIn(false)}, []);
```

I don't have the context of your application, but the main logic is to pass this boolean to false when user is not loggedin.

Also, I recommend you to externalize this logic via a hook for example "useAuthentication()". So the logic is separated from the render.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But what do you mean by  externalizing the logic via a hook for example "useAuthentication()"? I am new to the web dev thing and still confused for this hook thing.

Comment: I mean that it's a good practice to place all your useEffect logic (in this case) into a folder called hooks/useAuthentication.tsx (or .jsx).
Then in your component you'll call useAuthentication(); instead all of your useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

`Note: The storage event is only triggered when a window other than itself makes the changes.`

I found this on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_storage_url.asp